# A Generic Error Occured in GDI+ when resizing image

Tags: c#, jquery, gdi+

Ok, I am creating a photobooth application, and it's working.

I'm creating an image from a base64 string which I'm getting from a webcam Jquery plugin, then converting it to an Image using an Extension Method, and then trying to save it. The resolution of the image by default is 320 wide by 240 high.

Here's my code, that works.

```
var Image = model.Base64String.ToImage();
Image.Save("C:/PhotoRoute/" + model.ID + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

However, I realized later that I needed to change the resolution to 320px by 426px.

All I did is change the size of the image that was being taken by the plugin, all of my C# code is the same, and yet now I'm getting a "Generic Error Occurred in GDI+" error.

Could it be a problem of the image maybe being too large? What else could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it, although I'm not 100% sure why this worked.

I changed my code to this:

```
var Image = model.Base64String.ToImage();
var ResizedImage = new Bitmap(Image, new Size(144, 192));

ResizedImage.Save("C:/PhotoRoute/" + model.ID + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This worked, although I am not 100% sure why.

Further answers are greatly appreciated!!